# code-behind update of asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview

I have a GridView that is updated by code-behind code updating the SQL source by inputing text in a TextBox and clocking a button.  I have been searching for how to update the GridView after updating the SQL source, and I didn't find the answer. My code for the button click and SQL source changes are:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
         sqlSource.InsertParameters["x"].DefaultValue = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
         sqlSource.InsertParameters["y"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)this.FindControl("abc")).Text;
         sqlSource.InsertParameters["z"].DefaultValue = DateTime.Now.ToString();
         sqlSource.Insert(); 
    }
}
```

What do I add to this function so that the GridView is updated when the button is pressed?

Comment: gridView1.DataBind();

Comment: That code looks like it would never execute (why would you be entering the Button's click event if it's not a PostBack)?

Comment: you just rebind the grid after at the end of your RowUpdating event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Button click on ASP.NET need to be post back always. you write code just like page load event.

and for bind gridview from code write.

gridview1.datasource = sqlSource; 
gridview1.Databind();

Comment: I can't see if it works since my User.Identity.Name.ToString() gives the error: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. (System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)  Help?

Comment: Same thing  happens for the next line after commenting out the User.Identity one.